# Python Ending If Statement

Tags: python

How do I stop the if statement commands? In Java, you do this:

```
if (var==var2)
{
commands
} //how to do this in Python
```

In Java, you can do the same thing to end a for loop, or end really any conditional block. So, how do I do this in Python?

Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Thanks

Comment: same `if var == var2:`

Comment: This is not the place for an introduction to basic, fundamental Python syntax. You should start with the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial).

Comment: [Let me google that for you](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm)

Comment: Do you put a blank line?

Comment: Again, spend some time with the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

Python is control flows are regulated by indentation rather than curly brackets.

```
if (var==var2)
{
commands
}
```

becomes

```
if var == var2:
    commands

things_outside_of_IF_statement
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is much different from Java, there are no curly braces, rather Python relies on colons and indentation.

```
if var == var2:
    print "I'm in the if statement"
    print "So am I"

print "I am not"
    print "I am causing a indention error and this code won't run now"
```